# Maven doesn't create /target dir and no class files at all

Tags: maven

```
<properties>
    <testng.version>6.10</testng.version>
    <selenium.version>3.4.0</selenium.version>
    <compiler.version>1.8</compiler.version>
    <aspectj.version>1.8.10</aspectj.version>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <!--<repository>
        <id>jcenter</id>
        <name>bintray</name>
        <url>http://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
    </repository>-->
    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>Maven Repository Switchboard</name>
        <url>http://central.maven.org/maven2/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<build>
    <!--<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>-->
    <!--<testSourceDirectory>src/test/java/selenium/testng/tests</testSourceDirectory>-->
    <plugins>
       <!--<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${compiler.version}</source>
                <target>${compiler.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>-->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.20</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                <phase>test</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>test</goal>
                </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <suiteXmlFiles>
                            <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                        </suiteXmlFiles>
                        <testSourceDirectory>/src/test/java/</testSourceDirectory>
                        <!--<testClassesDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes/</testClassesDirectory>-->
                        <argLine>
                            -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                        </argLine>
                    </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <!--<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>-->
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Here is my POM file from project. When i run mvn compile it says that BUILD SUCCSESS, but in the project directory no target folder at all.

I tried to debug compile phase and i don't see any error messages in it.
I'm stuck with it, especially this is my first maven project. 
Is the my POM configuration correct?

P.S When i run mvn clean i see that maven-clean-plugin is used. 
When i run mvn compile i dont see similar text like "maven-compile-plugin:" in cmd window

My project structure:

```
src
   ---main
      ----java
          -----selenium
   ---test
      ---java
         ----selenium
             ----pages
             ----tests
```

Comment: Please post your full pom file...

Comment: in addition to not using the standard Maven directory structure, you have the compile plugin commented out, so, there's that

Comment: I have used your pom and comment out  following  its working fine  <configuration>   <suiteXmlFiles></configuration>                      </suiteXmlFiles

Comment: Adding to maven compile plugin goals is solved the problem

Answer (score 2):

Check your `pom.xml` content: `<packaging>` should not be `pom`.

Answer (score 0):

Maven defines a standard directory structure, if you are not following same Maven doesn't create /target dir and no class files at all

```
- src
  - main
    - java
    - resources
    - webapp
  - test
    - java
    - resources

- target
```

Example :

```
Vaquarkhan-app 
|-- pom.xml
`-- src
    |-- main
    |   `-- java
    |       `-- com
    |           `-- mycompany
    |               `-- app
    |                   `-- App.java
    `-- test
        `-- java
            `-- com
                `-- mycompany
                    `-- app
                        `-- AppTest.java
```

Comment: If the structure is not followed I guess the target is created to outermost folder.

Comment: I have checked project structure and looks like it fits haven requirements